# Convert a JavaScript String to an array

Tags: javascript

I have a Spring Controller which passes a Set of Strings to the view but as a single String:

```
"[AB, NK, LK]"
```

However, I need to convert the above String into an equivalent JavaScript array like the following:

```
["AB", "NK", "LK"]
```

I have tried the following jQuery to iterate through the String `"[AB, NK, LK]"` in order to add these values to a `<select>` tag:

```
$.each(arrayCodes, function(index, value) {
        $("#select").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + arrayCodeValues[index]
                + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: Why not have the controller give you valid JSON?  So you could `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yep, thought of that. However, I am passing a number of values (different values) to the view. In my case, it would actually be a lot more work. Of course, I would have shown my Java controller code, but it is out of the question's scope.

Comment: I agree with @RocketHazmat this sounds somewhat like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
var arr = "[AB, NK, LK]".slice(1,-1).split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression

```
var vals = "[AB, NK, LK]".match(/[A-Z]{2}/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the use of split function here if you want http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp this could solve your problem.

```
var sText = "[AB, NK, LK]";
var arrayCodes= str.split(",");

$.each(arrayCodes, function(index, value) {
        $("#select").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + arrayCodeValues[index]
                + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: Please prefer MDN references such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split to w3schools references when they're better http://www.w3fools.com